# ASP.NET 4 - url routing for images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i'm trying to route files like images from subfolder to root but don't have any idea to do this.
Also i've checked some scripts around the web, but nothing of these would work.

```
Source: /Projects/test/images/img.jpg
Destination: /images/img.jpg
```

I would be thankful for help.

Comment: I did not understand the question, can you please explain little more.

Comment: Can you actually elaborate what is that you want to do?

Comment: I want to route files from source to destination-path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Image", "Images/{file}",
                 new { controller = "Images", action = "Images" }
);
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Images(string file)
{
    path = "/Projects/test/images/" + file;
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    return File(path, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: And how can i get access on the result? There is no link between router and controller.

Comment: If you've created an "ImagesController" and route is above the standard one in global.asax you should be able to access it by surfing to /Images/somepicture.jpg

Comment: It works with the following entry:

<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>

Answer (score 1):

Use URL Rewrite rules for this.